# Searching for a registration/ticketing web app a.k.a. an alternative to Eventbrite?

Tags: webapp-rec

We are hosting a party and would like some form of ticketing web app to help with registration and collecting the ticket fees. Eventbrite is a good service, but it doesn't perfectly fit with our requirements, which are:

1. We would love to have two different ticket types, like one for premium and one for normal packages.
2. In addition to that we have a total number of tickets in each category to sell, such as 100 premium tickets and 40 normal packages.
3. The total number of tickets should be under some form of quota for men and women, as we want to have an equal number of men and women attending. Which is tricky, because during the signup period there may be times when we have, say, too many women, and we then want to have the extra women on a waiting list and only be admitted when extra men sign up.
4. we would also have the need for collecting extra data fields from the participants, such as food requirements (vegetarian, vegan,...?)

It would be great, if:

1. the web app automatically can send an email to people who bought their ticket
2. it can handle payment options such as PayPal, credit card and bank transfers in Europe
3. one can export lists of participants

Do you have an idea which web app/service could help?

Answer (score 1):

Two services you look at are [regonline](http://www.regonline.com)  and [Certain](http://www.certain.com).  Certain may be overkill for what you want, but what I think both of these are worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Pingg](http://www.pingg.com/info/products_and_features)?

They seem to cater for most if not all the features you are looking for.

List of features (some are paid features)

> - Invitation & eCard Designs
>
>   - pingg Gallery
>   - Designer Series
>   - Custom Design
>   - Your Image
>   - pingg Plus Designers
>   - pingg Vault
> - Connecting with your Audience
>
>   - Online pinggs
>   - Postal pinggs
>   - Digital Envelopes
>   - SMS
>   - Web
>   - Facebook
>   - Twitter
> - Guest List Creation & RSVP Management
>
>   - Import / Address Book
>   - Manual RSVP Management
>   - Group Invite Functionality
>   - Printing / Exporting
>   - Large Guest List Size
> - Personalized Event Web Pages
>
>   - Accessories: Photo, Videos, Maps, etc
>   - Ad-Free
>   - Customized Event Web Page URL
> - Gift & Charity Registries and Event Funds
>
>   - Integrated Gift Registry
>   - Integrated Charity Registry
>   - Collection Money
>   - Potluck
> - Guest Communications
>
>   - Reminder Messages & Thank You Notes
>   - Private Messages
> - Reporting & Event Stream
>
>   - Management Page
>   - Email Updates / News & Comments
>   - Total Headcount

Comment: Barry, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately they don't do anything with respect to ticket sales, or even guest list management/limits/quotas. The service just sends pretty invitations, it seems to me. So it's more about a party where you invite and manage from there – we want to sell tickets to people wanting to come, we may invite a few, but not all...

Answer (score 0):

have you considered [Ticketleap](http://www.ticketleap.com/)?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. As you browse the site you'll see that the better/more useful answers are longer and much more detail than yours. If you were to explain how and why your answer was relevant it would have the potential to become one of those answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [SignupMaster](https://www.signupmaster.com/html/benefits.htm).  You might be able to achieve the desired gender mix by using their "limited seats" and "waiting list" features.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Shastic](http://www.shastic.com/events/plans/?utm_source=webapps-stackexchange&utm_medium=post&utm_content=sell-tickets-for-free&utm_campaign=sell-tickets-online-for-free), a free ticketing service that is super easy to use, you can set it up in 2 minutes and you can use Paypal to receive payment instantly as each ticket is sold.

Comment: Please note if you are affiliated with a product you post about or you answer may be removed as spam.

Answer (score 0):

I think [EventHoller](http://www.eventholler.com) does everything you're looking for, it lets you create different ticket types and you can set limits on how many of each type are sold. It has a couple other cool features as well. It also accepts a variety of payment options, which you mentioned you are looking for. It also makes it easy for organizers and attendees to contact eachother, which would help solve your vegetarian issue. The best part is it's free. As someone who has managed events in the past, I am always annoyed by the $1+2% or whatever most sites charge. EventHoller is legitimately free to use, which is awesome.

Answer (score -2):

Next time you should try www.billetto.co.uk.

You can easily manage all your needs in their organiser interface and they promote your event for free to their community and through external blog partnerships..

Actually, it is more an event discovery platform, where the self-service ticketing just a minor feature.